# Kendo mvc grid conditon based action link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to access server side list into kendo mvc grid's ClientTemplate. I have tried a lot but didn't work.

Please look at my code

```
@{ List<Products> lstProducts = ViewBag.Products }
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model) .Columns(columns =>
 { columns.Bound(c=> c.CategoryId).ClientTemplate("# if (" + lstProducts.Count + " == 3) { #" + @Html.ActionLink("#= CategoryId #", "PatientStudyView", "Provider",new { sid = "#: UniqueID #" })"# } else {#" + 0 + "#}#");
```

it couldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put list of product in your model.
With that you will be able to access it like this #= Products #".
Or if you just need products count then add only that field in model.